# Can't draw after clearing graphics object in Flex

Tags: canvas, apache-flex, graphics, drawing

I have a small drawing application that I built some time ago. I just re-opened the project to add some improvements, but now whenever I call graphics.clear() I cannot draw again. I have reversed everything I have changed, but to no avail. Here is the relevant code from my custom drawing component (based on s:Group):

```
private var prevX:Number = 0;
private var prevY:Number = 0;

private function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false, 0, true);
}

private function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
    prevX = 0;
    prevY = 0;
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false);
}

private function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent) {
    //Set line style using graphics.lineStyle()

    graphics.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    graphics.lineTo(event.localX, event.localY);

    prevX = event.localX;
    prevY = event.localY;
}

public function clearCanvas():void {
    //After I call this I can no longer draw.
    graphics.clear();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Some additional info: startDrawing is called on MouseDown, stopDrawing is called on MouseUp, and clearCanvas is called from a button press. I also went from Flash Builder 4.6 to 4.7, not sure if there was an SDK change.

Edit: I worked on the code a bit today, and here is what I came up with. I can see the line when I click and drag, but for some reason can't redraw it onto the main canvas on the MouseUp. When I trace the code, it is transferring and apparently drawing everything correctly (although the smoothing mode is not working yet).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
         xmlns:local="*" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         mouseEnabledWhereTransparent="true"
         mouseDown="startDrawing(event)" 
         mouseUp="stopDrawing(event)">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.containers.Canvas;

            //########## Public Variables ##########

            public var __DrawingColor:uint = 0x000000;
            public var __DrawingWidth:Number = 4;
            public var __DrawingAlpha:Number = 1;
            public var __DrawingSmoothing:Boolean = false;

            //########## Private Variables ##########

            private static const ___SMOOTHING_AMOUNT:Number = 5;

            private var _History:ArrayCollection;
            private var _CurrentPoints:Array;
            private var _LiveCanvas:Canvas;
            private var _LiveObject:Object;
            private var _PrevX:Number = 0;
            private var _PrevY:Number = 0;

            //########## Public Functions ##########

            public function init():void{
                _History = new ArrayCollection();
            }

            public function clearAll():void {
                graphics.clear();
                _History = new ArrayCollection();

                graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0);
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
                graphics.endFill();
            }

            public function clearLast():void {
                if (_History.length > 0) {
                    _History.removeItemAt(_History.length - 1);
                    drawLines(_History);
                }
            }

            //########## Private Functions ##########

            private function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false, 0, true);
                _CurrentPoints = new Array();

                _LiveCanvas = new Canvas();
                addElement(_LiveCanvas);
                _LiveCanvas.x = 0;
                _LiveCanvas.y = 0;
                _LiveCanvas.width = this.width;
                _LiveCanvas.height = this.height;

                _LiveCanvas.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xFFFFFF);
                _LiveCanvas.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", "0");
            }

            private function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
                if (_PrevX != 0 && _PrevY != 0) {
                    _CurrentPoints.push(new Point(event.localX, event.localY));
                    _LiveCanvas.graphics.lineStyle(__DrawingWidth, __DrawingColor, __DrawingAlpha);
                    _LiveCanvas.graphics.moveTo(_PrevX, _PrevY);
                    _LiveCanvas.graphics.lineTo(event.localX, event.localY);
                }
                _PrevX = event.localX;
                _PrevY = event.localY;
            }

            private function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
                _CurrentPoints.push(new Point(event.localX, event.localY));

                _PrevX = 0;
                _PrevX = 0;
                this.removeElement(_LiveCanvas);
                _LiveCanvas = null;

                if (__DrawingSmoothing) {
                    _CurrentPoints = smoothPoints(_CurrentPoints);
                }

                var addItem:Object = new Object();
                addItem.color = __DrawingColor;
                addItem.width = __DrawingWidth;
                addItem.alpha = __DrawingAlpha;
                addItem.lines = pointsToLines(_CurrentPoints);

                _History.addItem(addItem);
                drawLines(_History);
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false);
            }

            private function smoothPoints(points:Array):Array {
                var len:uint = points.length;
                var p:Point;
                var ret:Array = new Array();
                var t:Number = 1 / ___SMOOTHING_AMOUNT;
                while (t < 1) {
                    p = getPoint(t, points);
                    ret.push(p);
                    t += 1 / ___SMOOTHING_AMOUNT;
                }
                return ret;
            }

            private function pointsToLines(points:Array):Array {
                var ret:Array = new Array();
                var lineObject:Object = new Object();
                for (var i:Number = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    if (!lineObject.hasOwnProperty("x1")) {
                        lineObject.x1 = Point(points[i]).x;
                        lineObject.y1 = Point(points[i]).y;
                    } else if (!lineObject.hasOwnProperty("x2")) {
                        lineObject.x2 = Point(points[i]).x;
                        lineObject.y2 = Point(points[i]).y;
                    } else {
                        ret.push(lineObject);
                        lineObject = new Object();
                        lineObject.x1 = Point(points[i]).x;
                        lineObject.y1 = Point(points[i]).y;
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }

            private function drawLines(lines:ArrayCollection):void {
                graphics.clear();
                graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0);
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
                graphics.endFill();
                var currentPoints:Object;
                for (var x:Number = 0; x < lines.length; x++) {
                    currentPoints = lines[x];
                    graphics.lineStyle(currentPoints.width, currentPoints.color, currentPoints.alpha);
                    for (var i:Number = 0; i < currentPoints.lines.length; i++) {
                        graphics.moveTo(currentPoints.lines[i].x1, currentPoints.lines[i].y1);
                        graphics.lineTo(currentPoints.lines[i].x2, currentPoints.lines[i].y2);
                    }
                }
            }

            private function getPoint(t:Number, points:Array):Point {
                var x:Number = 0;
                var y:Number = 0;
                var n:uint = points.length-1;
                var factn:Number = factoral(n);
                for (var i:uint=0;i<=n;i++) {
                    var b:Number = factn/(factoral(i)*factoral(n-i));
                    var k:Number = Math.pow(1-t, n-i)*Math.pow(t, i);
                    x += b*k*points[i].x;
                    y += b*k*points[i].y;
                }
                return new Point(x, y);
            }

            private function factoral(value:uint):Number {
                if (value==0)
                    return 1;
                var total:Number = value;
                while (--value>1)
                    total *= value;
                return total;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: I think you need to add more context for us to help.  When does startDrawing get called?  When does stopDrawing get called?  When does clearCanvas() get called?  It seems unusual that an app that used to work no longer works even though you reversed all your changes.

Comment: Thanks, I added a little more information above.

Comment: What is graphics? Is this a Flex project or an ActionScript only project?

Comment: The code shown above is a MXML component based on an s:Group, graphics is the group's graphics object. It is a Flex project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the working code is posted below if anyone is interested. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
         xmlns:local="*" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         mouseDown="startDrawing(event)" 
         mouseUp="stopDrawing(event)">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            //########## Public Variables ##########

            public var __DrawingColor:uint = 0x000000;
            public var __DrawingWidth:Number = 4;
            public var __DrawingAlpha:Number = 1;
            public var __DrawingSmoothing:Boolean = false;

            //########## Private Variables ##########

            private var _History:ArrayCollection;
            private var _CurrentPoints:Array;
            private var _LiveObject:Object;

            //########## Public Functions ##########

            public function init():void{
                _History = new ArrayCollection();
            }

            public function clearAll():void {
                graphics.clear();
                _History = new ArrayCollection();

                graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0);
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
                graphics.endFill();
            }

            public function clearLast():void {
                if (_History.length > 0) {
                    _History.removeItemAt(_History.length - 1);
                    drawLines(_History);
                }
            }

            //########## Private Functions ##########

            private function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false, 0, true);
                _CurrentPoints = new Array();
                _CurrentPoints.push(new Point(event.localX, event.localY));
                _LiveCanvas.visible = true;
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.clear();
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0);
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.endFill();
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.moveTo(event.localX, event.localY);
            }

            private function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
                _CurrentPoints.push(new Point(event.localX, event.localY));
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.lineStyle(__DrawingWidth, __DrawingColor, __DrawingAlpha);
                _LiveCanvas.graphics.lineTo(event.localX, event.localY);
            }

            private function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove, false);
                _CurrentPoints.push(new Point(event.localX, event.localY));

                _LiveCanvas.graphics.clear();
                _LiveCanvas.visible = false;

                if (__DrawingSmoothing) {
                    _CurrentPoints = smoothPoints(_CurrentPoints);
                }

                var addItem:Object = new Object();
                addItem.color = __DrawingColor;
                addItem.width = __DrawingWidth;
                addItem.alpha = __DrawingAlpha;
                addItem.points = _CurrentPoints;

                _History.addItem(addItem);
                drawLines(_History);
            }

            private function smoothPoints(points:Array):Array {
                var len:uint = points.length;
                var p:Point;
                var ret:Array = new Array();
                var t:Number = 1 / (points.length);
                while (t < 1) {
                    p = getPoint(t, points);
                    ret.push(p);
                    t += 1 / (points.length);
                }
                return ret;
            }

            private function drawLines(lines:ArrayCollection):void {
                graphics.clear();
                graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0);
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
                graphics.endFill();
                var currentPoints:Object;
                for (var x:Number = 0; x < lines.length; x++) {
                    currentPoints = lines[x];
                    graphics.lineStyle(currentPoints.width, currentPoints.color, currentPoints.alpha);
                    if (currentPoints.points.length > 0) {
                        graphics.moveTo(Point(currentPoints.points[0]).x, Point(currentPoints.points[0]).y);
                        for (var i:Number = 0; i < currentPoints.points.length; i++) {
                            graphics.lineTo(currentPoints.points[i].x, currentPoints.points[i].y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private function getPoint(t:Number, points:Array):Point {
                var x:Number = 0;
                var y:Number = 0;
                var n:uint = points.length-1;
                var factn:Number = factoral(n);
                for (var i:uint=0;i<=n;i++) {
                    var b:Number = factn/(factoral(i)*factoral(n-i));
                    var k:Number = Math.pow(1-t, n-i)*Math.pow(t, i);
                    x += b*k*points[i].x;
                    y += b*k*points[i].y;
                }
                return new Point(x, y);
            }

            private function factoral(value:uint):Number {
                if (value==0)
                    return 1;
                var total:Number = value;
                while (--value>1)
                    total *= value;
                return total;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas id="_LiveCanvas" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" backgroundAlpha="0" backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use your code and had the same issue. The solution by me was to fill the Group with a color, to make it accept mouse events again.

To have no changes of the background I used alpha = 0.

```
public function clearCanvas():void {
    graphics.clear();

    graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
    graphics.endFill();
}
```

If it doesn't help you, I'll post my code here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didn't seem to work. Please see my edit above with the full code.